# Ubuntu 12.04: Changing Hotkey for “Activities”

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, customization

I want to customize the hotkey for the Activities-overlay in Gnome shell in Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried to edit both:

> - /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu
> - /apps/mutter/general/overlay_key

with gconf but unfortunetaly it did not work.

My goal was to set <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as the new hotkey because I have some other OS's were Alt+Space has some similar functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply do that in Keyboard settings:

[image: Look under the 'Shortcuts' tab for something about 'Overview']
<sup>Gnome 3.10 - should be the same for most versions of Gnome 3</sup>

Gconf is deprecated - you are supposed to use dconf - which can be done simply using [`dconf-editor`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/).

You need to look for:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu
```

It should be in this format - it might cause problems otherwise:

```
['<Super>s', '<Alt>F1']
```

You can get the current value using:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu
```

And you can set the current value using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu 'VALUE'
```

In this case, `'VALUE'` would equal `"['<Alt>space', '<Alt>F1']"`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "'<Alt>space', '<Alt>F1'"
```

You can reset it using:

```
 gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu
```

As you can see, you can also use `gsettings` to change things - for a manual page on it run:

```
man gsettings
```

But it does the same thing as the keyboard settings dialogue.

Comment: Thank you very much!

This completely solved my problem :)